# Sorting a Vector of Vector in Cpp

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

Say I have this vector of vector `[[5,10],[2,5],[4,7],[3,9]]` and I want to sort it using the `sort()` method of cpp, such that it becomes this `[[5,10],[3,9],[4,7],[2,5]]` after sorting. That is I want to sort based on the second index.

Now I have written this code to sort this vector of vector, but it is not working correctly.

```
static bool compareInterval( vector<vector<int>> &v1, vector<vector<int>> &v2)
    {
        return (v1[0][1]>v2[0][1]);
    }
    

sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), compareInterval);
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong and hwo can I correct it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess the `compare` function should take a (reference to) vector-of-int, not a vector-of-vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your code is sorting vector of vectors then to the boolean function it passes two vectors (not vector of vectors), and compares them to determine if they need to be interchanged, or are they in correct positions relative to each other.

Hence, here you only need to compare 2 vectors (you have tried to compare vector of vectors).

The change you need to make in `compareInterval` is:

```
static bool compareInterval( vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2)
{
    return (v1[1]>v2[1]);
}
```

Find my testing code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

static bool compareInterval( vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2)
{
    return (v1[1]>v2[1]);
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> boxTypes = {{5,10},{2,5},{4,7},{3,9}};
        
    sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), compareInterval);
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        cout<<boxTypes[i][0]<<" "<<boxTypes[i][1]<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your sort could look like

```
std::sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs) {
    return lhs[1] > rhs[1];
});
```

in other words sorting by the `[1]` element of each vector and using `>` to sort in descending order. Note that in the lambda function `lhs` and `rhs` are of type `const std::vector<int>&`.

Answer (score 1):

Range projections will come somewhat handy for this.

`ranges::sort` algorithm would receive:

- just the vector to sort; no iterators to the begin and end.
- (optionally) the function you want to use for sorting, `greater` in this case.
- (optionally) the projection: for every element `t` of the original vector, which happens to be another vector of two elements, get its second element, i.e. `t[1]`, and sort on that.

```cpp
std::ranges::sort(boxTypes, std::ranges::greater{}, [](auto&& bt) { return bt[1]; });
```

Note I have only been able to have this compiling on msvc, not on gcc or clang (and with /std:c++latest, not even with /std:c++20; https://godbolt.org/z/9Kqfa9vhx).